# Подходит ли PyGame для создания серьезных проектов? И можно ли программу на PyGame компилировать под андроид\ios?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

Подходит ли PyGame для создания серьезных проектов? И можно ли программу на PyGame компилировать под андроид\ios?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pygame вряд-ли подойдёт для крупных проектов, максимум небольшие простенькие игры. Насчёт компиляции под ios не знаю, но под Андроид скомпилировать можно, т. к. в play market есть игры написанные с использованием данного модуля. Одним из самых ярких примеров подобных игр будет игра "one more cheese".

Comment: Можете посоветовать статьи как скомпилировать под Андроид. И какой модуль подойдёт для более крупных проектов?

Comment: @AhmedAyman123 боюсь, более крупные проекты на Питоне в принципе не делаются `(:` Для этого есть всяческие игровые движки, например, [libGDX](http://www.libgdx.ru), [GMS2](https://www.yoyogames.com), [Unity](https://unity.com/ru), [UE4](https://www.unrealengine.com/en-US/).